# Getting error using dynamic blocks in Terraform

Tags: terraform

The for_each line is where I get the error "Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token." I want to create that action based on a boolean variable. I already created a dynamic stage which works fine, but this dynamic action doesn't work.

How can I dynamically create this action?

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {

  stage {

  name = "Build"

  dynamic "action" {
  for_each = local.DoGovCloud ? [<<EOT
      name = "BuildInGovcloud"
     ...
      }
      EOT
      ]: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic "action" {
  for_each = local.DoGovCloud ? ["DoGovCloud"]: []
  content {
    //... properties of the action
  }
}
```

Will make an **action** block with the arguments in the **content** block if the value of **local.DoInGovCloud** is **true**.

Comment: Alain's code is correct, I guess just looking at this for the first time, a stage requires specific actions; even the Manual approval stage requires, at minimum, a name, category, version, and owner.  adding a dynamic action to a static stage will more than likely result in an error if no action is passed in based on the value.  I just wanted to throw that out there for readers who catch this post.

Comment: Very good point, @Maxamis4! You will definitely have to supply the required arguments to **action** in the content block or it will fail.